# What is wrong with this .create_margin_order() function using the Binance API

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to use the `.create_margin_order()` method for Binance API, but it doesn't work. Heres my code for the ordering function:

```
def limit_order(symbol, side, quantity, price, type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT):
    try:
        order = client.create_margin_order(symbol, side, quantity, price, type)
        output = {
            'status': True,
            'symbol': symbol,
            'side': side,
            'quantity': quantity,
            'price': price
            }

        print("Sending order:")
        print(output)
    except:
        output = {
            'status': False
        }
        print(symbol, side, quantity, price, type)
        print("There was an order error")
        return output

    return output
```

I'm using the `print` functions to try and look at the values and debug. Heres an example of a response:

```
BTCUSDT BUY 0.00030085801697862135 66476.54 LIMIT
There was an order error
```

All these numbers look good to me, the only thing I can think of is a minimum spend on Binance, but I'm pretty sure thats $10, and I've got some maths to ensure that the order is $20 every time.

The enabled settings in my Binance API management are:

Enable Reading
Enable Spot & Margin Trading
Enable Margin Loan, Repay & Transfer

and I have it set to Unrestricted while I am testing my application, my intention is to restirct access to trusted IP's once I have it running properly.

EDIT 1: I'm 100% sure its something to do with the create order method as I changed the code to this:

```
print('preorder')
order = client.create_margin_order(symbol, side, quantity, price, type)
print('postorder, preoutput')
```

and it only printed `preorder`

EDIT 2: Decided to use some other Binance API functions to try and debug this issue. I used `client.get_account()['permissions']` and found that this only returned `'SPOT'`. How do I fix my account to allow margin? I am able to margin trade on this account so I'm not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. And the margin accounts are trading on the spot market.

You need to consider the LOT_SIZE of an asset for the trading pair. The LOT_SIZE basically tells you the precision of an asset the exchange can handle.

> BTCUSDT BUY 0.00030085801697862135 66476.54 LIMIT
> There was an order error

The LOT_SIZE of BTC for BTCUSTD only allows for up to 10 decimals. Your amount contains twice as many decimals. So you need to format the amount or round it to the closest 10 decimal tik.